# Jenkins script to update job config: restricted agent and using docker container

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-api, jenkins-docker

I'm using a Jenkins script to update several jobs. I'm able to update the description, SCM credentials, and so on.

But I can't find how to :

- a) unset the option to restrict the agent (restrict where this project can be run)
- b) set the option "Docker container" (DockerJobProperty)

Jenkins version: 1.609.3

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,
Sébastien

Comment: I found the solution for (a) by setting the assignedLabel property of my Item to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can help someone else here is the answers.

a) `item.assignedLabel = null`

b) `item.addProperty(new com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerJobProperty(false, "", false, true))`

Regards